# JSON Can't pick any rows of my data array

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

Got an issue today, I can't pick any info of my JSON array.
Example of a row :

```
[{"0":"84","id_account":"84","1":"1500","count_soleillos":"1500","2":"2018-06-26 10:19:43","date_purchase":"2018-06-26 10:19:43","3":"Doe","name_account":"Doe","4":"Jhon","nickname_account":"Jhon","5":"standard","type_offer":"standard"},
```

And here is my javascript

```js
$.ajax({       
        type: 'POST',
        url: example/example.php,
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            var container = $('liste-offer');
            for (var i = 0; i <= jsonData.length; i++) {
                var counter = jsonData[i];
```

> Info : when I do jsonData.length, it returns 8 rows (exact). When I do
>   jsonData[0] or anything else, it returns undefined

Hope you could help me :)

Comment: Can you try `< jsonData.length;` instead of  `<= jsonData.length;`

Comment: share complete Ajax code ? and also complete JSON array

Comment: @The fourth bird It worked dude, I don't understand why, if someone could explain me ! Anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: @McManuel Great that it worked. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `< jsonData.length;` instead of `<= jsonData.length;` because you are [indexing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) into the object and that has 8 properties instead of 9. Then `<=` will match 0 till 8 inclusive and `jsonData[8];` does not exist and will give you `undefined`.

You could update your code to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access any key by below way:

jsonData[0]['id_account'] or jsonData[0].id_account

For exact solution please update your question with complete JSON and with your JavaScript method

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  alert(jsonData[i].id_account);
  var counter = jsonData[i]; 
}
```